# How to place image inside UILabel on start of UILabel text?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uilabel

Hi I wanna add image round dot to some UILabel in my app.

I have code for adding the image. But I don't understand how I could put the image on the start of the UILabel rather than in the end of the label.

Any suggestion on this? Below is the code I use for it:
What should I add to place image on start of UILabel? I thought imageBehindText :false would fix it but it didn't.

```
extension UILabel {
/**
 This function adding image with text on label.

 - parameter text: The text to add
 - parameter image: The image to add
 - parameter imageBehindText: A boolean value that indicate if the imaga is behind text or not
 - parameter keepPreviousText: A boolean value that indicate if the function keep the actual text or not
 */
func addTextWithImage(text: String, image: UIImage, imageBehindText: Bool, keepPreviousText: Bool) {
    let lAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    lAttachment.image = image

    // 1pt = 1.32px
    let lFontSize = round(self.font.pointSize * 1.20)   // rounded dot should be smaller than font
    let lRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height

    lAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: ((self.font.capHeight - lFontSize) / 2).rounded(), width: lRatio * lFontSize, height: lFontSize)

    let lAttachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: lAttachment)

    if imageBehindText {
        let lStrLabelText: NSMutableAttributedString

        if keepPreviousText, let lCurrentAttributedString = self.attributedText {
            lStrLabelText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: lCurrentAttributedString)
            lStrLabelText.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: text))
        } else {
            lStrLabelText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        }

        lStrLabelText.append(lAttachmentString)
        self.attributedText = lStrLabelText
    } else {
        let lStrLabelText: NSMutableAttributedString

        if keepPreviousText, let lCurrentAttributedString = self.attributedText {
            lStrLabelText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: lCurrentAttributedString)
            lStrLabelText.append(NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: lAttachmentString))
            lStrLabelText.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: text))
        } else {
            lStrLabelText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: lAttachmentString)
            lStrLabelText.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: text))
        }

        self.attributedText = lStrLabelText
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a horizontal stack view and call it a day?

Comment: How would I do that? Do you mean that I should use another label specific for the image?

Comment: Here's a quick tutorial on stack views. I love them. They do a lot of "book keeping" for you and they're easy to animate, etc. https://www.raywenderlich.com/2198310-uistackview-tutorial-for-ios-introducing-stack-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. The problem was that I was setting the text in the storyboard(.xib). So this extension didn't change the image to the front even if the bool-val were false.

Simply set the text from the function-call and the 'false' value will trigger the image to be set in the start of the uilabel.

Example1 (what I did wrong):

```
// This is what I tried first!
    label.addTextWithImage(text: "",
                                       image: UIImage(named: embededIcon)!,
                                       imageBehindText: false, // note! This is false.
                                       keepPreviousText: true) // this was the problem!
```

Example2 (what got it to work!):

```
label.addTextWithImage(text: "putYourLabelTextHere!",  // You have to put text here, even if it's already in storyboard.
                                   image: UIImage(named: embededIcon)!,
                                   imageBehindText: false,
                                   keepPreviousText: false) // false, so the image will be set before text!
```

Comment: Good that you figured it out. One thing I would encourage you not to do is force unwrap (`!`). A better way to deal with an optional would be to either use `if let emdeddedIcon = whateverYourImageIs { do stuff }` or `guard let embeddedIcon = whateverYourImageIs else { return }`. Alternatively, you could just provide a blank image, so the 2nd parameter would be `image: UIImage(named: embeddedIcon) ?? UIImage(),`

Comment: Wow I really missed that one. Thank you very much for this warning! I'll go with the alternative solution you provided, ?? UIImage().

Comment: I have no idea what your view looks like, but if you're guaranteed text but the image is optional, `if let` might be the best bet and you could do `else { set the text and hide the image }`. Anyway, you know what they say about opinions. This is more of a 6 vs. half dozen issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. The embeddedIcon always have text-ref to assets, if that's what you meant. The problem with going for guard let or let is that the var embIcon is not a let e.g. will change icon. I'm afraid there will be wrong icon if I go with let key-word since the var always will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
lazy var attachment: NSTextAttachment = {
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = UIImage(named: "")
    return attachment
}()
```

it will work for both remote and local image

```
if let imageUrl = imageUrl, imageUrl.count > 0, let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
let imageAttachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: (titleLabel.font.capHeight - 16) / 2, width: 16, height: 16)
BaseAPI().downloadImage(with: url, placeHolder: "") { [weak self]  image, error, success, url in
    if let image = image, let self = self {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let finalString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
            let titleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.title)
            let space = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " ")
            let imageAttachment = self.attachment
            imageAttachment.image = image
            finalString.append(imageAttachmentString)
            finalString.append(space)
            finalString.append(titleString)
            self.titleLabel.attributedText = finalString
        }
    }
}
```

} else {
titleLabel.text = title
}